# Confused why react component not rendering from data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to figure out why certain markup from my react component is not rendering. No errors are being thrown.

I am passing the component data of the form:

```
const moduleData = {
    openTickets: {
        title: 'Open Tickets',
        stats: [
            [ //rows
                {
                    stat: 2,
                    desc: 'New',
                },
                {
                    stat: 2,
                    desc: "Unseen for > 24 hours",
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    stat: 32,
                    desc: 'In Progress'
                },
                {
                    stat: 2,
                    desc: 'In progress for > 1 week',
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}

...

<DashboardModule data={moduleData.openTickets}/>
```

and that DashboardModuleComponent is as follows:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';

function DashboardModule(props) {
    const {data} = props;
    return(
    <div className="dashboard__module">
        <div className="dashboard__module_header">
            <h3 className="dashboard__module_title h2">{data.title}</h3>
        </div>
        {
            data.stats.forEach((statRow,index)=>{
                console.log(statRow,index);
                return (
                    <div className="dashboard__module_row" key={`module_row--${index}`}>
                        {
                            statRow.forEach((stat,statIndex)=>{
                                console.log(stat.stat);
                                return (
                                    <div key={`stat_container--${statIndex}`}className={`dashboard__module_stat_container ${statIndex === 0 && 'primary'}`}>
                                        <p className="dashboard__module_stat">{stat.stat}</p>
                                        <p className="dashboard__module_desc">{stat.desc}</p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div >
    );
};

export default DashboardModule;
```

The console logs give the correct data, but there is no markup after the:

```
<div className="dashboard__module_header">
    <h3 className="dashboard__module_title h2">{data.title}</h3>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use map not forEach

Comment: i'm not sure why this question got downvoted

Comment: I agree, question seems valid, downvote should be removed.

Comment: well, to be fair...at this point I should probably know when to use map and foreach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` just traverses the collection, not returning the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use data.stats.map() instead of foreach()